# How to round/ceil/floor a bcmath number in PHP?

Tags: php, largenumber, bcmath

Is there any library function for this purpose, so I don't do it by hand and risk ending in TDWTF?

```
echo ceil(31497230840470473074370324734723042.6);

// Expected result
31497230840470473074370324734723043

// Prints
<garbage>
```

Comment: See also my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
$x = '31497230840470473074370324734723042.9';

bcscale(100);
var_dump(bcFloor($x));
var_dump(bcCeil($x));
var_dump(bcRound($x));

function bcFloor($x)
{
    $result = bcmul($x, '1', 0);
    if ((bccomp($result, '0', 0) == -1) && bccomp($x, $result, 1))
        $result = bcsub($result, 1, 0);

    return $result;
}

function bcCeil($x)
{
    $floor = bcFloor($x);
    return bcadd($floor, ceil(bcsub($x, $floor)), 0);
}

function bcRound($x)
{
    $floor = bcFloor($x);
    return bcadd($floor, round(bcsub($x, $floor)), 0);
}
```

Basically it finds the flooy by multiplying by one with zero precision.

Then it can do ceil / round by subtracting that from the total, calling the built in functions, then adding the result back on

Edit: fixed for -ve numbers

Comment: +1, but it might be worth adding a scale argument to bcCeil and bcRound, as the behaviour is dependent on the scale.  If you call `bcscale(0)` then try bcCeil('1.1') you're going to get '1' not '2' as you might expect.  Allowing the scale to be specified would be consistent with the other BCMath functions.

Comment: Also to note, the scale argument should be default null and should not overwrite the value set by `bcscale` if not provided.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE: See my improved answer here: [How to ceil, floor and round bcmath numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers/1653826#1653826).**

---

These functions seem to make more sense, at least to me:

```
function bcceil($number)
{
    if ($number[0] != '-')
    {
        return bcadd($number, 1, 0);
    }

    return bcsub($number, 0, 0);
}

function bcfloor($number)
{
    if ($number[0] != '-')
    {
        return bcadd($number, 0, 0);
    }

    return bcsub($number, 1, 0);
}

function bcround($number, $precision = 0)
{
    if ($number[0] != '-')
    {
        return bcadd($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
    }

    return bcsub($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
}
```

**They support negative numbers and the precision argument for the bcround() function.**

Some tests:

```
assert(bcceil('4.3') == ceil('4.3')); // true
assert(bcceil('9.999') == ceil('9.999')); // true
assert(bcceil('-3.14') == ceil('-3.14')); // true

assert(bcfloor('4.3') == floor('4.3')); // true
assert(bcfloor('9.999') == floor('9.999')); // true
assert(bcfloor('-3.14') == floor('-3.14')); // true

assert(bcround('3.4', 0) == number_format('3.4', 0)); // true
assert(bcround('3.5', 0) == number_format('3.5', 0)); // true
assert(bcround('3.6', 0) == number_format('3.6', 0)); // true
assert(bcround('1.95583', 2) == number_format('1.95583', 2)); // true
assert(bcround('5.045', 2) == number_format('5.045', 2)); // true
assert(bcround('5.055', 2) == number_format('5.055', 2)); // true
assert(bcround('9.999', 2) == number_format('9.999', 2)); // true
```

Comment: Won't work with integers. Good realisation of these functions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1653826/541961
Alix, you can edit your post to link to the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for my [**high-precision Money library**](https://github.com/phpexpertsinc/MoneyType), which is currently on hundreds of production sites, I had to completely rewrite this bcround functionality. Nothing I found on the entire Internet was up to code.

Here's what I came up with:

```php
/**
 * Based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653826/430062
 * Thanks, [Alix Axel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel)!
 *
 * @param $number
 * @param int $precision
 * @return string
 */
function bcround($number, $precision = BCMathCalcStrategy::PRECISION)
{
    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        if ($number[0] != '-') return bcadd($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
        return bcsub($number, '0.' . str_repeat('0', $precision) . '5', $precision);
    }

    // Pad it out to the desired precision.
    return number_format($number, $precision);
}
```