# bcmath seems to give the wrong answer to my calculation

Tags: php, bcmath

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this calculation

```
bcscale(20);
echo bcmul(bcdiv('422218', '2388865'), '473');
```

echoes "83.59999999999999999670" but every other calculator gives me 83.6.

Is there a way to solve this or is it a flaw in bcmath?

Comment: That seems a construed example. Why don't you reorder the operations or simply use ordinary PHP float arithmetic if that is what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see this result is because you **first** perform the division.

The division gives you:

```
422218/2388865
0.17674418604651162790697674418604651163
```

but you ask for **20** digits, so that becomes `0.1767441860465116279`. In that light, bc gives you now the correct result:

```
0.1767441860465116279*473
83.5999999999999999967
```

A **"solution"** in this case would be to first perform the multiplication (which gives you "just" 9 digits) and then the division:

```
bcscale(20);
echo bcdiv(bcmul('422218','473'),'2388865');
83.60000000000000000000
```

Comment: Yes! a proper solution without trickery. thank you! And now i think i will go and brush up on my math :)

Answer (score 1):

The bcmath functions use *arbitrary* precision arithmetic. The calculations aren't 100% precise - they're only as precise as you ask for (you asked for scale 20). Since the calculations aren't precise you can't always expect the answer to be precise.

You say that your calculator gives you the correct answer in this case. But assuming that it also uses arbitrary precision arithmetic (most do) it will give you the wrong answer in other cases. Some calculators hide their inaccuracy by calculating with a greater precision than they can display (for example an extra two digits). If you perform a calculation where the error builds up it will eventually become visible in the display.

Comment: Yeah that makes a whole lot of sense, thank you for setting my tired brain straight!

Answer (score 0):

BCMath gives you exact result. If you need other number "form", use functions like `round()` to change it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

For example:

```
echo round(bcmul(bcdiv('422218', '2388865'), '473'), 1);
```

Will give you 83.6.

Comment: The exact result is `418/5` or `83.6`.

Comment: By "exact" result I mean exact number that is calculated by computer - as someone said it has limited precision, so result will be also "limited".

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I see what i have done wrong and i will most likely use something like this to solve it, found a nice bcround() function in another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers) that i think i will use to cut down the precision on the numbers i display.

Comment: @Tomasz I think this answer is misleading and hides the underlying problem. In this case, for example, you can just swap the order of div and mul and have the exact, correct result. Please, since it's the accepted answer, at least make a comment for that.

Comment: @Eelvex how do you mean should i run 473*(422218/2388865) ? that seams to give me the same answer as above..

Comment: @Zzzarka: I mean `(473*422218)/2388865`; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083380/bcmath-seams-to-give-the-wrong-answer-to-my-calculation/5083529#5083529)

Comment: It's no longer accepted answer, so no comment is needed. ;] But I'd argue if I'm supposed to make any comment - it's a numeric problem, but given this exact code my answer is correct.

Comment: @Tomasz: Off course it's correct; it's just that `round` as a solution is kind of misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified more precision (20 digits) than most calculators can carry. So they'll round it off, most likely to 10 or 15 digits, giving 83.5999...99, which rounds to 83.6.