# (PHP) How to avoid scientific notation and show the actual large numbers?

Tags: php, floating-point, scientific-notation

I have been working with the PHP code that the expected result will become :

> 1
>   
> 101
>   
> 10001
>   
> 1000001
>   
> 100000001
>   
> 10000000001
>   
> 1000000000001
>   
> 100000000000001
>   
> 10000000000000001
>   
> 1000000000000000001

finally the output was :

> 1
>   
> 101
>   
> 10001
>   
> 1000001
>   
> 100000001
>   
> 10000000001
>   
> 1000000000001     // (1 billion) **to** (100 billion - 1) still showing the actual number, and then
>   
> 1.0E+14
>   
> 1.0E+16
>   
> 1.0E+18

I've found some solutions there! they said by using **sprintf** or trying **format_number**. I tried both.

using **sprintf** and the result :

```
$format_x = sprintf("%.0f ",$x);
echo $format_x.$br;
```

> 1
>   
> 101
>   
> 10001
>   
> 1000001
>   
> 100000001
>   
> 10000000001
>   
> 1000000000001
>   
> 100000000000001
>   
> 10000000000000000
>   
> 1000000000000000000

using **format_number** and the result :

```
echo number_format($x, 0).$br;
```

> 1
>   
> 101
>   
> 10,001
>   
> 1,000,001
>   
> 100,000,001
>   
> 10,000,000,001
>   
> 1,000,000,000,001
>   
> 100,000,000,000,001
>   
> 10,000,000,000,000,000
>   
> 1,000,000,000,000,000,000

but it still doesn't show the actual large numbers. well, the two ways was looks good but it doesn't fit with what i want. does anyone can resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use standard [bc_math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library to handle operations with large numbers. Please, note, that in this case your numbers will be represented as strings, but library provides specific methods for operations under such strings.

Comment: For integers - may be. But topic starter mentioned 'large numbers' - i.e. could be floats.

Comment: i just knew the bc_math function. can you help me how the bc_math works on the code above? i've tried bcpow but doesn't work. is must include the bcpow's function first on my php file?

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use BCMath.

If you want to know why you can't do it with regular numbers, it's because they are floating point numbers and they are using a fixed amount of space in the memory(64 bits to be exact) so their precision is physically limited. Otherwise a string is not limited because that would be stupid if the length of a text was limited. That's why BcMath and other libraries uses string for arithmetical computation.

If you want to learn more about the format used by PHP(and almost every language) to store big numbers you can go there : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Have a good day