# PHP - Find the number of zeros in a decimal number

Tags: php, decimal

Let's say we have 0.00045.  I want to find a way to count the number of "significant" zeros after the decimal point (3 in this case).  I've been trying to implement `strpos` or `substr`, but I'm getting stuck.

Other exs....

3.006405: Should return "2"
0.0000062: Should return "5"
9.0100000008: Should return "1"

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `strspn()` to find the length of the sequence of zeroes.

Comment: Okay so significant 0's, will probably involve using a loop. I would try converting the decimal to a string, iterating through it with a loop and use a bunch of if statements to check the various significant figure rules. If all if statements work out, just have a counter and increment it.

Comment: Is it right after the decimal point? Do they have to be consecutive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
strspn($num, "0", strpos($num, ".")+1)
```

`strspn` finds the length of a sequence of zeroes. `strpos` finds the position of the decimal point, and we start from 1 position past that.

However, this doesn't work for `0.0000062` because it gets converted to scientific notation when converted to a string: `6.200000e-6`. When the number ends with `e-<exponent>`, the number of zeroes is `<exponent>-1`. You can check for this with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to investigate some different possibilities in handling this task.

I must say that Barmar's solution is easy to read and well suited for floating point numbers that do not suffer from impacts of scientific notation.

As a thought experiment, I've decided to craft a couple of regular expressions to do the same job. (*The regex approaches will still hold up even if you pass an integer value to them.)

1. With `preg_match_all()`, I am using the "continue" metacharacter (`\G`) to match the first `.0` then zero or more `0` that immediately follow.
2. With `preg_match()`, I can more simply match the dot, then "forget it" with `\K` (restart the fullstring match), then match 1 or more zeros from that position.  Unfortunately this requires the additional call of `str_len()`.  I generally only favor `preg_` calls when it results in fewer function calls than non-regex approaches.

Inspired by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219601/141885, I wanted to write a function to count the zeros after the decimal point using only arithmetic (guess & check).  **While it doesn't suffer from scientific notation like the others, it is imperfect and there are limits to floats/integers on different operating systems / versions / environments / yatta-yatta (I don't pretend to know all of the ins-and-outs, but I am aware that there are differences).**  Go ahead and try some of these approaches with your project data and feel free to leave comments about what works and doesn't work. ...and if you know know *why* I invite you to educate me :)

Finally, there are many posts on StackOverflow ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18328332/2943403)) that recommend using the standard php library [BCMath](https://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GoZaF))

```
function mathematical_zeros_after_dot($float) {
    $float = abs($float);  // remove any signs
    $float -= (int)$float;  // remove whole numbers from float
    if ($float == 0) {
        return "Rendered as 0";
    }
    $max = 20;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $max; ++$x) {  // for loop with a hard limit to avoid infinite loop
        $float *= 10;
        if ($float >= 1) {
            return $x;
        }
    }
    return "$max {exceeded}";
}

$floats = [
    25.000000000022,         // 10
    0.0000062,               // 5
    0.020320,                // 1
    .505000,                 // 0
    0,                       // 0
    .000507,                 // 3
    -.002009,                // 2
    1000,                    // 0
    0.00,                    // 0
    1                        // 0
    -1.0000000000004000004,  // 12
    981.0000000000000000000004000004  // 21
];

foreach ($floats as $float) {
    echo "(Math) {$float} has " , mathematical_zeros_after_dot($float) , " zero(s)\n";
    echo "Barmar {$float} has " , strspn($float, "0", strpos($float, ".")+1) , " zero(s)\n";
    echo "(PMA) {$float} has " , preg_match_all('~(?:\.|\G(?!^))0~', $float) , " zero(s)\n";
    echo "(PA) {$float} has " , (preg_match('~\.\K0+~', $float, $match) ? strlen($match[0]) : 0) , " zero(s)\n";

}
```

Output:

```
(Math) 25.000000000022 has 10 zero(s)
Barmar 25.000000000022 has 10 zero(s)
(PMA) 25.000000000022 has 10 zero(s)
(PA) 25.000000000022 has 10 zero(s)
(Math) 6.2E-6 has 5 zero(s)
Barmar 6.2E-6 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) 6.2E-6 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 6.2E-6 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) 0.02032 has 1 zero(s)
Barmar 0.02032 has 1 zero(s)
(PMA) 0.02032 has 1 zero(s)
(PA) 0.02032 has 1 zero(s)
(Math) 0.505 has 0 zero(s)
Barmar 0.505 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) 0.505 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 0.505 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) 0 has Rendered as 0 zero(s)
Barmar 0 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) 0 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 0 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) 0.000507 has 3 zero(s)
Barmar 0.000507 has 3 zero(s)
(PMA) 0.000507 has 3 zero(s)
(PA) 0.000507 has 3 zero(s)
(Math) -0.002009 has 2 zero(s)
Barmar -0.002009 has 2 zero(s)
(PMA) -0.002009 has 2 zero(s)
(PA) -0.002009 has 2 zero(s)
(Math) 1000 has Rendered as 0 zero(s)
Barmar 1000 has 3 zero(s)
(PMA) 1000 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 1000 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) 0 has Rendered as 0 zero(s)
Barmar 0 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) 0 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 0 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) -3.9990233346998E-13 has 12 zero(s)
Barmar -3.9990233346998E-13 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) -3.9990233346998E-13 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) -3.9990233346998E-13 has 0 zero(s)
(Math) 981 has Rendered as 0 zero(s)
Barmar 981 has 0 zero(s)
(PMA) 981 has 0 zero(s)
(PA) 981 has 0 zero(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the first consecutive zeroes in the mantissa:

```
$number = 123.0000000240003;

preg_match("/^(0+)/", explode('.', $number)[1], $matches);

echo strlen($matches[0]); // echoes 7
```