# HTML output based in input number in PHP

Tags: php

I have values like so:

```
0.00000500
0.00003491
0.00086583
1.45304093
```

etc

I would like to run these through a PHP function so they become:

```
<span class="text-muted">0.00000</span>500
<span class="text-muted">0.0000</span>3491
<span class="text-muted">0.000</span>86583
1.45304093
```

What I have now is:

```
$input_number str_replace('0', '<span class="text-muted">0</span>', $input_number);
$input_number str_replace('.', '<span class="text-muted">.</span>', $input_number);
```

This is a bit 'aggressive' as it would replace every character instead of using the `<span>` once, but I guess that's OK, even if I have say 1000 numbers on a page. But the biggest problem I have is that my code would also 'mute' the last 2 digits in `0.00000500` which I don't want.

Comment: Check out... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801385/php-find-the-number-of-zeros-in-a-decimal-number

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
$input_number = str_replace('0.', '', $input_number);
```

We are replacing **0.** with empty string

Secondly:

Use [preg replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$newNumber = preg_replace('/^0?/','<span class="text-muted">0</span>',$input_number);
```

Basically **/^0?/** is looking for leading 0's which will replace with span, you can also replce with empty or anything you want.

Comment: The result here is `<span class="text-muted">0</span>00003491` so two errors: the period (.) is not there anymore, and it does not produce the desired result (all zero's have the `<span>`)