# Safely round numbers in php using strings to avoid evil float

Tags: php, string, casting, floating

I use `bcmath` for my calculations and I want to round some numbers to `n` decimal places. Now, I know enough to avoid floats, but what I'm wondering is if the following example is safe and/or if there are better ways to do it?

```php
$number = '123.456'; // number to round as string
$roundedNumber = (string) round($number, 2); // round and cast
// calculations using bcmath continue here...
```

I **think** it is, I've ran some experiments and so far it always returned expected result but I'd like second opinion as I'm not 100% positive that in some particular case casting string to float and then float back to string will not output undesired result.

Or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT: before you answer:**

`bc*` functions do not **round** when third parameter is specified, they just trim the output.

`number_format` does not allow selection of rounding mode, so it's out

**EDIT: What do I consider safe?**

Given the number as string and rounding mode, will the function always output correct/expected result and not be affected by casting to float?
I guess that what I'm being afraid of is following:
I provide number say 12.345 as string to `round` function, it gets casted as `float` and then my number isn't 12.345 anymore, it may be 12.345xxxx because we all know how `float` can be represented internally. I'm afraid of that affecting the rounding output. I believe there will be no harm when I cast to 12.345 to string, it will always be '12.345', not '12.345....' right?

Comment: Define "safe". What are the possible conditions under which this has to work? If you're using `bcmath` everywhere, then why not write your own `round()` routine that works purely with strings? For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653826/3986005

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ceil, floor and round bcmath numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642614/how-to-ceil-floor-and-round-bcmath-numbers)

Comment: None of the solutions posted in the question both of you linked does not account for rounding mode. I'd like to keep it simple and use what already exists unless I absolutely need to write my own implementation. I'll edit the question to define safe.

Comment: You're right, casting to floats is not "safe". You could adapt the `bcround()` function, I refered to, to any rounding mode you want, even all of them.